# create a mask opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a binary CV::Mat with one channel and a vector of points representing a polygon I want to make a binary mask based on the polygon

```
std::vector<cv::Point> my_poly = {cv::Point(150, 100), cv::Point(500, 150), cv::Point(500, 700), cv::Point(150, 500)};
cv::Mat mask  = cv::Mat::zeros(1280, 720, CV_8U);
```

How can I make the zeros inside the mask turn to one where the my_poly area cover

Comment: Just call the drawing function: `cv::fillPoly(mask, my_poly, cv::Scalar::all(1));`

Comment: Yes that solves the issue thanks, you can but the comment as an answer so I can close the question